# OpenCV FaceRecognition issue - it almost always matches images

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a Face Recognition project, using OpenCV.

I am training all the 3 recognizers (Eigen,Fisher, LPBH) using the CvHaarClassifierCascade. The problem is that FaceRecognition::predict almost always predicts a match.

For example, let's say I have 10 images per person and I have 2 persons. When person #1 sees the camera, prediction works. When person #2 sees the camera, prediction also works.

However when I have only 1 person, then when person #2 sees the camera, LPBH almost always matches it to person #1. That is, when the person looking the camera is not included in the training classes, LPBH almost always matches him.

Are there parameters I could configure the LPBH with in order to avoid this behaviour ?
I want it to reject "unknown" persons.

Best Regards.

Comment: "However when I have only 1 person, then when person #2 sees the camera" <- does this mean you train only one face and then expect it to distinguish different people? In this case sure it cannot do it. Classifier tells who is most similar from trained ones and confidence index. It cannot solve problems other than trained for.

Comment: So what would be the most correct approach to take when creating a system in which an unknown person must be rejected?

Comment: Yes, look into confidence value and reject based on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classifier can be trained to make difference between TRAINED examples. If you want to reject samples which look somewhat different, check for confidence level. Classifier basically tells "I think, this is person #1 but my confidence is 0.39 from possible maximum 1.0".

Comment: Actually there is no standard confidence level returned from the trainers, but thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: Confidence level is returned by classifier, not trainer. I know, I am using them :)